# How to perform a Franklin Reiter Related Message Attack on RSA?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

By definition, the Franklin Reiter related message attack works in a scenario where two messages differ only by a fixed known difference. Suppose I have two messages encrypted by RSA with the same public key (N, e), where:

> M1 = "Hello " + name1 + message

> M2 = "Hello " + name2 + message

How can I perform the Franklin-Reiter related message attack on them?

I am aware that we need (N, e, C1, C2, f) for a Franklin Reiter related message attack where f = ax + b, but what is f in this case?

Comment: Wrong Q/A site, please take a look [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=Reiter+related) before asking on [crypto.se].

Comment: And besides not deleted from here before/after asking in Cryptography.se